# scatter plot interaction coefficients in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following regression:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + categorical + categorical*x1)
```

I would like to make a scatter plot where the points are the intercept and slope for the different categories. That is (categorical_1, categorical_1:x1), (categorical_2, categorical_2:x1), (categorical_3, categorical_3:x1)... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please try to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), these help respondents better understand and diagnose your issues.  I think for the example that you are describing, I would create a dataframe of the model parameters by category, and plot them on the same scatterplot.  Below is a reproducible example.  Unfortunately, the only way I can think of to accomplish what you are after is rather manual.

```
##Load the dplyr:: package, install if not installed##
if(!require(dplyr)){
  install.packages("dplyr")
}

##Creating fake data to model##
x1<-rnorm(50, 25, 3)
x2<-rnorm(50, 10, 2)
cats<-c("A", "B", "C")
cat_var<-sample(cats, 50, replace=TRUE)
errors<-rnorm(50, 0.8, 0.05)

##Creating a dataframe of the fake data and forcing different slopes and intercepts for modeling##
dtf<-data.frame(X1=x1, X2=x2, CAT=cat_var, E=errors) %>% mutate(Y=case_when(CAT=="A"~1.53+1.86*X1+2.31*X2+E,                                            CAT=="B"~2.03+3.02*X1+2.31*X2+E,                                                                           TRUE~3.03+5.02*X1+2.31*X2+E,))

##Running an OLS model##
mod<-lm(Y~X1+X2+CAT+CAT*X1,data = dtf)

##Extracting the Slopes and Intercepts from the model##
##Note, the model gives us slope and intercept differences##
##Between catagories, so we need to add those difference to the reference catagory##
slopes<-c(mod$coefficients["X1"], mod$coefficients["X1"]+mod$coefficients["X1:CATB"], mod$coefficients["X1"]+mod$coefficients["X1:CATC"])
ints<-c(mod$coefficients["(Intercept)"], mod$coefficients["(Intercept)"]+mod$coefficients["CATB"], mod$coefficients["(Intercept)"]+mod$coefficients["CATB"])
catagories<-factor(c("A", "B", "C"))

##Plotting the data##
plot(x=NA, Y=NA, xlim=c(0,4), ylim=c(0,max(slopes,ints)*1.25), xlab=NA, ylab=NA, axes=FALSE)#Create a plotting frame

points(slopes~catagories, col="blue", pch=16, cex=1.5) #Add the slopes 
points(ints~catagories, col="darkorange", pch=17, cex=1.5) #Add the intercepts
axis(1, at =c(0,1,2,3,4), labels=c(NA,"A", "B", "C", NA))#Put in the X axis
axis(2)#put in the Y axis
title(xlab="Catagory", ylab="Parameter Estimate", main="Fake Linear Model") #Add titles back in
legend("topleft", legend=c("Intercept Values", "Slope Values"), pch=c(17, 16), col=c("darkorange", "blue"), cex=1.5)#Create a legend to label points
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
tmp.df <- cbind(as.data.frame(state.x77), state.division)
fit <- lm(Murder ~ 0 + state.division + state.division:Frost + Income,
data=tmp.df)
cf <- coef(fit)
plot(cf[1:9], cf[11:19])
```

The `0 +` part (which could also be a `-1`) tells `lm` to not fit an intercept, then we also do not fit a main effect for `Frost`, so that we have a coefficient for every `state.division` and for each slope/interaction.  I skipped coefficient 10 because that is the slope on income.  Some manual inspection of the return value of `coef` was used to determine which values to include where.